# Why can't I install Phusion Passenger for nginx?

Tags: software-installation, nginx

I'm trying to install phusion passenger.

```
passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Eventually I got an error

```
Permission problems

This installer must be able to write to the following directory:

  /opt/nginx

But it can't do that, because you're running the installer as alex.
Please re-run this installer as root.
```

I tried to do to

```
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

but it says

```
sudo: passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Passenger installation with nginx fails in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225881/passenger-installation-with-nginx-fails/5326724#5326724:):

> The correct way of running the Phusion Passenger installer for nginx,
>   when using RVM, is to use rvmsudo as in:
>
> ```
> rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
> ```
>
> Credits go to [this blog post](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2010/10/passenger-3-nginx-and-rvm-on-mac-os-x.html).

Comment: `/usr/bin/env: passenger-install-nginx-module: No such file or directory`

Comment: not using rvm using rbenv please update answer for rbenv users also.

Comment: @vidurpunj I've also using rbenv. I solved it by running: `which passenger-install-nginx-module` then running that with sudo. In my case it was: `sudo ~/.rbenv/shims/passenger-install-nginx-module`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using rbenv instead of rvm, so rvmsudo isnt an option for me.

I solved it by running:
`which passenger-install-nginx-module` then running that with sudo.

In my case it was:

`sudo ~/.rbenv/shims/passenger-install-nginx-module`

Answer (score -2):

open your terminal and type this to create a user as deploy .

```
sudo adduser deploy
```

then do Update and install required dependencies with this command

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev curl git-core python-software-properties
```

then we have to install Ruby

```
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz
tar -xvzf ruby-1.9.3-p194.tar.gz
cd ruby-1.9.3-p194/
./configure
make
sudo make install
echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" >> ~/.gemrc
sudo gem install bundler
```

Then now we are able to install Nginx with Passenger , with these commands

```
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

Hope that helps .

> **Source**: http://excid3.com/blog/setting-up-ubuntu-12-04-with-ruby-1-9-3-nginx-passenger-and-postgresql-or-mysql/

Comment: E: Unable to locate package passenger-install-nginx-module

Comment: @AlexMaslakov answer edited

Comment: I don't need to install  ruby, curl, etc. I already have them! I just need to install passenger as root.

Comment: I used rvmsudo instead. It works.

Comment: you can edit my Answer to improve the answer . Glad u got it .